# Every finite group is isomorphic to the Galois group of some polynomial

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I was reading through chapter 14 of Dummit and Foote just now and I came across the sentence  "It is an open problem to determine whether every finite group appears as the Galois group for some polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$" and I was wondering 2 things:

1. Is it known whether each finite group is the Galois group of some polynomial (not necessarily over $\mathbb{Q}$)?
2. Why is this problem so hard? (I know this question may defy a simple answer, but from the very naive perspective of someone who knows very little--me--it isn't very clear why this should be too much harder than the abelian case considering what is known about the structure of finite groups in general)

thanks :)

Comment: For (1), see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132665/every-finite-group-is-isomorphic-to-some-galois-group-for-some-finite-normal-ext. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem.

Comment: My naive understanding of your second question is that 
1) Abelian groups have a much simpler structure. That is, given an abelian number field, EVERY subextension is Galois because every subgroup of the Galois group is normal! This is wildly false for non-abelian number fields.
2) We do not understand Artin $L$-functions at all as well as we do Dirichlet $L$-functions. The proof I've seen of the Inverse Galois problem for abelian groups is using Dirichlet's theorem on primes in Arithmetic progressions which is proved using the latter.

Comment: @lhf Thanks! You found that reference fast!

Comment: @Arkady is your comment above about Artin $L$-functions being mysterious suggesting that there is a proposed approach to settle the inverse Galois problem over $\mathbf Q$ if we only were able to establish certain properties of Artin $L$-functions? I've never heard anything like that before.

Comment: @KCd Not at all. I don't think what I wrote out in 2) was well thought out at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, every finite group is the Galois group of some extension. Consider the field $K = \mathbb{Q}(e_1, \dots e_n)$ and its extension $L = \mathbb{Q}(x_1, \dots x_n)$ where the $x_i$ satisfy

$$\prod (t - x_i) = \sum (-1)^i e_i t^{n-i}$$

where $e_0 = 1$, so the $e_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in the $x_i$. Then $L$ is a finite Galois extension of $K$ with Galois group $S_n$ (exercise). Since every finite group $G$ embeds in some $S_n$, we get finite Galois extensions $L$ of fields $L^G$ with Galois group $G$.

The inverse Galois problem is hard not because we don't know enough about finite groups but because we don't know enough about the Galois theory of $\mathbb{Q}$. It's equivalent to showing that every finite group is a quotient of the absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$, and this is just hard. The abelian case is much easier because abelian quotients of the Galois group are handled abstractly by [class field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_field_theory) and concretely by the [Kronecker-Weber theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%E2%80%93Weber_theorem), but "nonabelian class field theory" is much harder, not completely understood, and very much the subject of active research.

Comment: Since we know how to realize all the groups $S_n$ for $n \geq 2$ as Galois groups over $\mathbf Q$ (e.g.,, use the splitting field of $x^n - x - 1$) and every finite group is a *subgroup* of some $S_n$, every finite group is a Galois group over some finite extension of $\mathbf Q$.  You could say what makes the inverse Galois problem hard is that we can't realize every finite group as a *quotient group* of some $S_n$.  Indeed, for $n \geq 5$, the quotient groups of $S_n$ have size $1$, $2$, and $n!$.

Comment: Don't we need $G\triangleleft S_n$, for the first part to work?

Comment: @hawaiian: please reread the argument. We only need $G$ to be a subgroup, but the price we pay for that is we only get a Galois extension of $L^G$; in other words we have to allow the base field to vary. That's why this argument does not solve the inverse Galois problem, which fixes the base field.